# How can I keep randomizing a text in Java?

Tags: java, random

I just want to know, maybe you can help me.
Heres the code,maybe you can edit it.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public ststic void main string(args[]){
    System.out.println("I want to keep randomize between  following texts:")
    //abc_123_def
    //jaofn_3vfdsa
    //nabdoew-8943
}
```

Comment: A quick google search and you can find some articles. Like this -> https://www.baeldung.com/java-random-string

Answer (score 0):

You can store the different `String` in a `List`, then shuffle it

```
System.out.println("I want to keep randomize between  following texts:");
List<String> texts = Arrays.asList("abc_123_def", "jaofn_3vfdsa", "nabdoew-8943");

Collections.shuffle(texts);
System.out.println(texts); // [jaofn_3vfdsa, abc_123_def, nabdoew-8943]

Collections.shuffle(texts);
System.out.println(texts); // [abc_123_def, nabdoew-8943, jaofn_3vfdsa]
```

You can customize printing, with a `join` for example

```
System.out.println(String.join(", ", texts)); // abc_123_def, nabdoew-8943, jaofn_3vfdsa
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you asked for...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
 //task: show one of these texts randomly every time the user answers "yes"
    String[] text = {"abc_123_def", "jaofn_3vfdsa", "nabdoew-8943"};
    boolean bored = false;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (!bored) {
        System.out.println("Would you like to keep randomizing?");
        if (s.nextLine().equals("yes")) {
            int rand_n = (int) Math.round(Math.random() * 2);
            System.out.println("Random text: " + text[rand_n]);
        }
        else {bored = true;}
    }
}
```